# jQuery Ajax return HTML data unable to parse in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a HTML out put in in the Ajax Call like this

```
<div>
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
</div>
```

In my jQuery I am trying to identify the div elements like the following and add them in 
a container.

```
$.ajax({
    url: requestURL?queryString,
    success: function (data) {
        /// i is increment by for loop ..for simplicity I am leaving that logic.
        container.add(i,$(data).children('#one').html());

        // another case
        container.add(i,$(data).children('#two').html());

        // another case
        container.add(i,$(data).children('#three').html());
    }
});
```

The scenario is working in FireFox not in IE
I have tried like `$(data).find('div#one')` and `$(data).children('div#one')` but nothing is working.

Appreciate your help

Comment: What is `container`, is it a jQuery element?

Comment: Yes, it is carousel container

Answer (score 0):

Check the api of [.add](http://api.jquery.com/add/).

If you pass two parameters, `.add( selector, context )`, then the 
first parameter should be a string representing a selector expression to find additional elements to add to the set of matched elements. Have your `i` done the right thing?

Comment: Yep, but the container is the carousel container which need the position as index and content as TEXT / HTML. I am doing work around ...It works good in Fire Fox as usual :) having trouble in IE, The problem I am suspecting IE unable to parse the DOM what AJAX returns...or it may need well formed..

Comment: I just added a Alert for debug purpose   alert($(data).html()) retruns the html content in FF but null in IE, do you have any Idea

Answer (score 0):

I have done some work around for this issue, that fix the children method for IE.
1) I have added DOCTYPE on the top of return HTML and cleaned all the white space in return HTML.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <div>
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
    </div>

$(data).children('div#one').html();
```

works Good Tested both in IE & FireFox.

Thansk